# forgotten key pair needed for bastion host to connect to rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am trying to set up a bastion host to connect to my rds in AWS, but I have forgotten the key pair that I need in order to configure it. Is there a way to retrieve it or make a new one so I can configure the bastion host? If so how would I go about it?

Comment: If you have lost your key you'll have to start over. There is no recovery option.

Comment: ok, when i create a new file and I want to ssh through mysql workbench, should I use .pem file or .ppk when creating a new key pair?

Comment: I _think_ that MySQL Workbench would use PEM. Only PuTTY uses PPK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, if you have no important data or configuration on the Bastion server, then it would be easiest to terminate it and launch a replacement.

However, if you wish to regain access to the instance, there's a couple of methods.

**Create an AMI**

- Create an image (AMI) of the current bastion
- Launch a new Bastion from that AMI, specifying a new keypair

This works because software installed in Amazon Linux will automatically add the nominated keypair to the `ec2-user` user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

**Manual editing**

- Stop the Bastion
- Detach the root volume
- Launch another (temporary) instance
- Attach the disk from the Bastion as an additional drive
- Edit the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and add the public half of new keypair
- Detach drive
- Reattach to Bastion
- Start the Bastion

That makes the AMI method look easier, eh‽

Answer (score 0):

Replace with new one bastion. This is easiest way to resolve this issue. 
If your bastion store important data, create new ebs from snapshot ebs volume old bastion then attach to newly bastion.